# Powershell to delete files from SharePoint Document libraries

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to multiple files from multiple SharePoint libraries in SharePoint 2010 on Application server in the farm with the below script:

```
$list = Get-Content $libpath
$web = Get-Spweb $url
$lib = $web.Lists | where { $_.title -eq $libname }
foreach ($libr in $lib) {
  $file = $libr.Items
  foreach ( $fil in $file) {
    If ($fil.Name -eq $item) {
      $fil.Delete()
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that `$libr.Items` is coming up empty even though the library is not empty.

```
$libr.Files 
$libr.Files.Name
```

All showing up empty as well.

Please help in fixing it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "Provide your web here"
$docfiles = $SPWeb.GetFolder("Provide your Document Library name here").Files
foreach ($docfile in $docfiles) {
    Write-host "File Name: " $docfile.Name 
    $docfile.Delete();
}
```

Comment: Added a write-host $docfiles it is appearing empty. It is not going into foreach too.

Comment: Try running $SPWeb.GetFolder("Provide your Document Library name here") and check what you get?

Comment: It’s getting the library name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this does:

```
$lib = $web.Lists | where { $_.title -eq $libname }
foreach ($libr in $lib) {
```

$lib in this case should be a single library, why the foreach?
Can I suggest you get the library explicitly then verify that it exists:

```
$lib = $web.lists.TryGetList($libname)
if ($lib) {
    $items = $lib.items
    foreach ($item in $items) {
        #Your logic here
        #Do you really want to delete? Maybe use $item.Recycle()
    }
}
```

Also if you know what you want to delete up front, look into batching as you can delete items much faster.

Comment: Yeah the foreach($libr in $lib) does nothing, I commended it on actual code, added here by mistake. I am getting run time exception on TryGetList(). “You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression”

Comment: Does your $web object exist?

Comment: Yes it does, yeah sorry, I miss typed the url while editing, now $lib comes blank...

Comment: Can you verify that the library name is correct? Use $web.Lists | select title and confirm that $libname is in the list and is spelt correctly.

Comment: $web.lists[“ListTitle”] gives the ListTitle but TryGetList(“ListTitle”).Files still comes up empty

Comment: Ok, so to be clear $list = $web.Lists["ListTitle"]; $list.ItemCount works? If that works then your list exists and the TryGetList will work too. I have my doubts you are getting a valid list...

Comment: ItemCount works, but not TryGetList! It is a document library!

Comment: A doclib is a type of list. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee563106(v=office.15). But if it works by indexing for the library just use that i.e. $lib = $web.lists.[$libname]